# HTML won't scroll

Tags: css

On my site, http://www.granthpark.me/outside If I resize my browser to smaller sizes, my content will be hidden and I can't scroll to it. Can anyone point out what's making the content fixed?

Here is the CSS, can't post it here because it's too long http://www.granthpark.me/assets/css/main.css

EDIT: New problem. I can scroll now because I tried replacing every instance of position:fixed with absolute in addition to changing overflow:hidden to scroll. But now I don't know how to fix the margin of my background to resize properly when I resize the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple replace the style sheet, you will get rid of all the problems. [click to see](http://mhk.me/main.css)

Comment: This was the closest to what I wanted to achieve. Do you know how to keep the filtered layer on parallax in addition?

Comment: I didn't get you,  can you please describe me. Also approve my answer :)

Comment: the diagonal patterned background does not resize properly

Comment: If I am not wrong then you want to fixed this Diagonal Patternedon scrolling ?

Comment: Yes, if I scroll down, it doesn't continue

Comment: Go to file main.css > line no.309. Changed the value of property position:absolute; to position:fixed;

Comment: You can ask me related question on info@mhk.me.

Answer (score 2):

add property in body tag this in css:
`body{overflow: scroll;}`

Comment: Tried it, but it's still the same

Comment: It only works if I change all instances of position: fixed to absolute, and when I do that, I don't know how to fix the margins of my background when I resize

Answer (score 1):

Change your body's property to `overflow: scroll;`

Right now your `overflow` property is set to `hidden`.

```
body {
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but it's still the same

Comment: I tried changing every instance of position: fixed to absolute in the css, and I can scroll now; but now I don't know how to fix the margins to make the background fixed with resizing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the culprit:

```
body {
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

add this property in body tag:

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

In css file "main.css" line no. 934 add this property in id `#bg`

```
Position:Fixed
```

Comment: First you've to see the problem then you should comment.